# Volume under intersection of 2D Gaussians

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Given 2 2D Gaussian functions (probability cdfs, if that matters), is there a direct method to calculate the volume under their intersection?

If not, are there any quick ways to approximate it? (speed being more important than accuracy)